# Too many arguments to `LTrim`

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error in my program.

> *Too many arguments to `Public Function LTrim(str As String) As String`.*

```
Dim fortrim As String
Dim trimed As String
fortrim = TextBox1.Text
trimed = LTrim(fortrim, 3)
'                       ^
'               error appears here
TextBox2.Text = trimed
```

Help is appreciated. I can't find a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really suggest you to remove the old VB6 functions and use the more advanced NET equivalent.

[string.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
[string.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)
[string.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.TrimStart(Nothing)
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Instead, (looking at your comment in a different answer) if you want to extract the last 3 chars from a string the method to use is [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and the property [string.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx)

```
 Dim original = TextBox1.Text
 Dim last3 = original
 ' be sure to have at least 3 chars before doing substring math
 If last3.Length > 3 Then
    last3 = original.Substring(original.Length - 3, 3)
 End If
 TextBox2.Text = last3
```

Comment: Hi sir steve,

thanks for your reply, reading about functions you have said.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as it states, you have more arguments than what is expected.

So change

```
LTrim(fortrim, 3)
```

to

```
LTrim(fortrim)
```

You could also shorten this code to something like

```
TextBox2.Text = LTrim(TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Hi Sir astander, 

thanks for your reply,
error does not appear when i remove "3" , but im trying to get the last 3 character of the string on my textbox1.text

Comment: thanks sir for your reply.. learned about the meaning of that error.

Comment: @iGNRev -If you're trying to get the last three characters of the string, then you don't want any of the `Trim` functions - those remove white space.  You'll want to look into `String.Substring()`